# How do i form a query for jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, jdbctemplate

am trying to form a query based on parameters, if the parameters for WHERE clause is null or not. it seems to be a huge code if i do this on if and else. Is there any other smart way to this??

example :

```
String query = "SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE WHERE ";
if(cust_id !=null && !(cust_id.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")))
{
    query = query + "cust_id='"+cust_id+"'";    
}
else
{

}
```

checking all the columns like this, the code is looking like a mess, please let me know if there is an other way to do this

adding to the above question :

I also have the parameters for like operator

example

```
if(strCustName!=null)
{
    String query = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME LIKE '"+strCustName+"';
}
```

Comment: Use a `Map` with the column name as the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NamedParameterJDBCTemplate](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-named-parameters-examples-in-simplejdbctemplate/)

And your query could be

```
... WHERE (cust_id=:custIdParam OR :custIdParam is null)
      AND (another_column=:another_param OR :another_param is null)
```

UPDATE:

```
String sqlstr = "select * from the_table where lastname like :lastname or :lastname is null"

NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jt = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(datasource);

Map namedParameters = new HashMap();
namedParameters.put("lastname", "%test%");
SqlRowSet result = jt.queryForRowSet( sqlstr ,namedParameters );
```

from [the link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/33677-how-to-use-like-in-where-clause-of-sql-for-namedparameterjdbctemplate)

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but  i have one more problem, what if can we do to have that in like operator

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer but when i have null value for named parameter its giving me an exception - org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter

Comment: Anyway you need to put null value for parameter.

Comment: namedParams.put("serialnumber", (strSerialNum == null || strSerialNum.trim().length()==0) ? null : (strSerialNum.toUpperCase()+"%")); i have this but still its the same problem

Comment: Is the "serialnumber" just one? Any other parameters? Could you post more code - real SQL and parameters map entries.